# Не ровняются элементы с inline-block

Tags: html, css, inline

Никак не могу выровнять два элемента с инлайн-блок. Должны идти в ряд с одинаковой высотой. Идут в ряд, но первый элемент ниже, второй выше.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

```css
.support {
  font-size: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.support-text p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.support-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #ccc;
}

.support-logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.support-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background: rgb(0, 12, 48);
}
```

```html
<section id="support" class="support">
  <div class="support-text">
    <p>ПРИ ПОДДЕРЖКЕ МЕЖДУНАРОДНОЙ<br> ОБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНОЙ КОМПАНИИ<br> и Т.Д.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="support-logo"></div>
  <div class="support-line"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Я бы лучше использовал для контейнера `support`  `display: flex;` С этим inline-block намучаетесь...

Comment: @Вероника добавьте `vertical-align:top;` к классу `.support-text` или к `.support-logo`

Comment: Благодарю! Вертикальное выравнивание сработало!

Comment: К сожалению, до флексов еще не дошла, но чувствую, что уже надо) Благодарю за советы и ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .support {
      font-size: 0px;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 25px;
    }

    .support-text p {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: 17px;
    }

    .support-text {
    /*--добавить выравнивание--*/
      vertical-align: top;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 500px;
      height: 110px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: 500;
      background: #ccc;
    }

    .support-logo {
    /*--добавить выравнивание--*/
      vertical-align: top; 
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 110px;
      background: #F7F7F7;
    }

    .support-line {
      width: 100%;
      height: 7px;
      background: rgb(0, 12, 48);
    }
    <section id="support" class="support">
      <div class="support-text">
        <p>ПРИ ПОДДЕРЖКЕ МЕЖДУНАРОДНОЙ<br> ОБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНОЙ КОМПАНИИ<br> и Т.Д.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="support-logo"></div>
      <div class="support-line"></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить overflow: hidden; для блока с текстом.

Comment: Благодарю! тоже помогло! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Это работающий способ, но лучше сделать на флексах или грид... просто удобнее.